# Bypassing an SQL Error 264 - column name is specified more than once in the SET clause

Tags: sql-server

I've been instaling one of our products on a new test server and it's not working due to an error 264 - the column name 'kod_novy' is specified more than once in the SET clause.

I know where the problem is and reported it to the development for a fix. But we have the same application deployed and it works just fine.

In the code you can see the 'kod_novy' is used twice in the insert. My question is - does anyone know, how did our customer manage to ignore this error and successfully complete the T-SQL? Is that a server setting?

Thanks,
Z

```
insert into [server].db.dbo.prenos_c_banky (
    id_prenos, 
    kod, 
    kod_novy, 
    ext_kod,
    iud_job,
    kod_banky,
    kod_novy,
    nazev,
    znacka)
select 
       cast('2B06FB0A-2664-4714-91F6-A6D39BDE5B5F' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), 
       kod, 
       kod_novy,  
       ext_kod,
       iud_job,
       kod_banky,
       kod_novy,
       nazev,
       znacka 
from #c_banky
```

Comment: You can't bypass it. You can't insert 2 values into the same column. If you're trying to to that, you're misunderstanding how SQL works. Perhaps you need to tell is what the actual problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: Can't see that it's possible to do. The more logical explanation is that the other environment used a different script.

Comment: There was probably some dynamic SQL involved. Perhaps these columns come from two different tables, one of which didn't have that column originally.

Comment: The code was taken from a profiler on our customer's server. I expected it to fail just like on our test machine but somehow the whole operation finishes without any problems. That is my question @Larnu - how is it possible?

Comment: *"how is it possible?"* it isn't.

Comment: And yet it actually happens on a daily basis without any errors.